# How to stack multiple Visual Studio solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I've been trying to find some clear documentation on best practices with regard to nesting Visual Studio solutions. Please bear with me if the terminology is wrong - I'm not really experienced in creating significant solutions.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a website that is a web application in VS speak - so it is my solution.

The site will have some reusable functionality. Normally I would just create a class library project and have done with it.

However, in this case the functionality is database driven via Entity Framework. If I was creating a self contained project, I would create a new solution, containing 3 library class projects for BLL, DAL and Entities.

So instead, I'm thinking a second solution containing the 3 class libraries - obviously I don't need a second front end as the primary web application will do the job.

So, I have a number of options as far as I can see:

- Create a new solution as described above that can be plugged into my
  main solution - but what do I do with the unwanted project that
  contains the App_Data, Account folders etc?
- Create a single class library and create visual separation through
  folders.
- Create 3 separate class lib projects (although this gives least
  benefit)
- Or, something else I'm not aware of.

Sorry if this sounds basic to you guys that do this day in day out, but I just don't have the necessary experience to make the right call.

Comment: _"I'm thinking a second solution containing the 3 class libraries"_ - why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a website that will incorporate dynamic data from the database. I plan to use the same data on other websites - it's not just the database, but also the entities and views I wan't to replicate. Effectively it means I can just create a new from end and incorporate the service, or any other service I create this way with ease.

Comment: You know a project can be present in multiple solutions? Do you _need_ project references, or is packaging them up and referencing them as NuGet packages also an option?

Comment: I don't need to package them as Nuget packages - they are for internal use only. However there are various ways of referencing them and I know from the little experience I have that a wrong call now, can be painful further down the line.